# How to store user data in session using Wicket?

Tags: session, authentication, wicket

*I am learning Wicket using "Wicket in Action" book.*

### What I did (safe to skip)

I would like to create such workflow:

- user opens the page for the first time -- "user not logged in" is printed out
- user goes to log-in page
- user logs in (successfully)
- user is redirected to main page -- and info about user is printed out

It is all described in the book, and in theory it looks OK. There is a class for user data (`UserData`), and there is class session (`MySession`) which holds user data. Session is created in Wicket `MyWebApplication`, on call of `newSession` method.

But the result is -- it does not work.

### The problem

User data are deleted just after successful logging in. The problem is creating session:

- entering the page, plus
- going to log-in page, plus
- getting back to main page

results in 6 created sessions. Of course each new session kills previous one, and with it all data.

**Question:** so how to store user data in session properly, or rather how to make a session work like a real session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it! It seems Wicket drops session (by default) on purpose, so if one wants to keep it, she/he has to state it explicitly by calling `bind` on session. More about it in Craig Tataryn post:

http://basementcoders.com/2008/10/sessions-in-wicket/